Flutter FVM and dependencies
The situation is like this, I connected to the project, there is an old version of flutter and fvm configuration files. I set myself an fvm, bent the project and installed the desired version of flutter. But when executing the fvm flutter pub command, get the packages in pubspec.I don't have any problems with yaml (I skipped the project from the main branch, which lies in the prod, there are no conflicts). There is a configured path to the fvm flutter SDK in the code/settings file.json ("dart.flutterSdkPath": ".fm/versions/3.10.6"). Has anyone encountered this, can you give me some advice?
I tried to add thefvm to the PATH, but it did not help, and the documentation does not say that it is necessary to update the PATH environment

what is the actual issue you are getting?

@SujanGainju
Resolving dependencies...
Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on collection 1.17.1 and eds_mobile depends on collection ^1.18.0, flutter_test
from sdk is forbidden.
So, because eds_mobile depends on flutter_test from sdk, version solving failed.

I gave up using fvm a while ago once I discovered https://puro.dev.  Better, faster, easier to use.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
